# Parsing error : invalid syntax (line 1) from ArcGIS Raster Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster-calculator

I have a (Aspect)raster (32bit, floating point,overall 2.9GB) of a landscape and need to devide it with π/180, in order to get the mean aspect later.

My raster calculator (Spatial Analyst --> Map Algebra --> Raster Calculator ) says:

> Python-Syntaxfehler: Parsing error : invalid syntax (line 1)

when I click onto it to calculate it.

What does that mean and how can I work with this raser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your expression, but without having the expression it is impossible to know what exactly is wrong. My guess is that if you give an approximate value for Pi something like

```
"your_raster_file.tif" / (3.14159265 / 180)
```

it will work.